# Unapply regex matching into case class

Tags: scala

Given a regex and a string

```
val reg = "(a)(b)"
val str = "ab"
```

and a corresponding case class

```
case class Foo(a: string, b: string)
```

How can I match the regex against the string and unapply the matches
into the case class so I have

```
Foo("a", "b")
```

in the end?

Answer (score 2):

Pattern match on the result of finding the regular expression in the string and assigning the results to `Foo`. The API [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/matching/Regex.html) for Regex have a similar example.

```
scala> val reg = "(a)(b)".r
reg: scala.util.matching.Regex = (a)(b)

scala> val str = "ab"
str: String = ab

scala> case class Foo(a: String, b: String)
defined class Foo

scala> val foo = reg.findFirstIn(str) match{
     | case Some(reg(a,b)) => new Foo(a,b)
     | case None => Foo("","")
     | }
foo: Foo = Foo(a,b)

 scala> foo.a
res2: String = a

scala> foo.b
res3: String = b
```

Comment: No way to avoid the intermediate step of assigning the variables `a` and `b`? Because in my actual use case, there are 6.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the match is ok, you can currify the function and use a foldleft to apply this version to the list of extracted arguments:

```
> val reg = "(a)(b)".r
> val str = "ab"
> val f1 = (Foo.apply _).curried
// f1 : String => String => Foo
> val groups = reg.findFirstMatchIn(str).get.subgroups
// groups: List[String]
> val foo = ((f1 : Any) /: groups) { case (f: (String => Any), s) => f(s)} asInstanceOf[Foo]

foo: Foo = Foo(a,b)
```

See [Function2](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function2) in scala for the definition of curried.